# How to reinstall the libzip distribution when build lumen in docker

Tags: laravel, docker, lumen

I use docker version Version 17.12.0-ce-mac55 (23011) on osx version 10.11.6. I have a problem when I build lumen on docker, but when the build process is finished there is an error like this :

> configure: error: Please reinstall the libzip distribution ERROR:
>   Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update
>   && apt-get install -y libpng-dev libjpeg-dev libpq-dev     && rm -rf
>   /var/lib/apt/lists/*     && docker-php-ext-configure gd
>   --with-png-dir=/usr --with-jpeg-dir=/usr     && docker-php-ext-install gd mbstring pdo pdo_mysql pdo_pgsql zip' returned a non-zero code: 1

This is my dockerfile settings:
[image]

So the build process fails. Has anyone ever had a case like me? I hope someone can provide a solution.

Comment: did you try adding ```apt-get install libzip-dev```? you may need to install that first.

Answer (score 18):

Try to configure zip with libzip and install libzip-dev

```
#install some base extensions
RUN apt-get install -y zip libzip-dev \
  && docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip \
  && docker-php-ext-install zip
```

With Alpine version :

```
RUN apk add --no-cache libpng-dev zlib-dev libzip-dev \
&& docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip \
&& docker-php-ext-install zip
```

Comment: `docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip` gives me an error: `configure: error: unrecognized options: --with-libzip`

Comment: Using `FROM php:7.3-apache` this is what finally worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

RUN rm composer.lock && composer install 
--optimize-autoloader 
--no-interaction 
--no-progress 
--ignore-platform-reqs

RUN apk add --no-cache php 
php7-common 
php7-fpm 
php7-pdo 
php7-opcache 
php7-zip \